# MQTT, issue when making receiving iOS swift app

Tags: ios, swift, server, message, mqtt

I am trying to make an app which receives data from my raspberry pi, I am using MQTT as a server, but when i am trying to make the message receiving app it doesn't work. Is there someone with some experience regarding to MQTT and iOS who can help me out.

Code:

```
import Moscapsule


class ViewController: UIViewController {

// set MQTT Client Configuration
let mqttConfig = MQTTConfig(clientId: "iOS Device", host: "192.168.178.27", port: 1883, keepAlive: 60)
    mqttConfig.onConnectCallback = { returnCode in
        NSLog("Return Code is \(returnCode.description)")
    }

    mqttConfig.onMessageCallback = { mqttMessage in
        NSLog("MQTT Message received: payload=\(mqttMessage.payloadString)")
    }

    // create new MQTT Connection
    let mqttClient = MQTT.newConnection(.mqttConfig)

    // publish and subscribe
    mqttClient.publishString("message", topic: "publish/topic", qos: 2, retain: false)
    mqttClient.subscribe("subscribe/topic", qos: 2)

    // disconnect
    mqttClient.disconnect()

}
```

these are the errors I am getting
[My Xcode Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3CmN.png)

Comment: This is nothing to do with mqtt. These are just Swift syntax errors because you have arbitrary code outside of any functions and you have an unnecessary . In front of mqttConfig. You need to move this code into a function such as `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Why you are calling disconnect at the end? MQTT connection will be disconnected and your app will not recieve messages.